# Dynamic Validation of ASP.NET controls using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, validation

I have multiple controls that need validation based on one condition: if one of the three controls have values, the fourth one must also contain a value. I have 4 sets of 4 controls, each numbered from one to four. I've written a quick and dirty function for validation, but it the code itself is unholy and defies most of the principal of good code design, its really ugly.

**JavaScript Validation**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           $("#<%= submitBtn.ClientID%>").click(function () {
            var errorMessage = "";
            var error = false;

            var firstname1 = document.getElementById("<%=child1FN.ClientID%>").value;
            var surname1 = document.getElementById("<%=child1LN.ClientID%>").value;
            var relation1 = document.getElementById("<%=ddlRelationship1.ClientID%>").value;
            var dob1 = document.getElementById("<%=DoB1.ClientID%>");
            if ((firstname1 != "" || surname1 != "" || relation1 != "") && dob1.value == "") {
                errorMessage += "First DoB needs to be filled. \n";
                error=true;
            }

            var firstname2 = document.getElementById("<%=child2FN.ClientID%>").value;
            var surname2 = document.getElementById("<%=child2LN.ClientID%>").value;
            var relation2 = document.getElementById("<%=ddlRelationship2.ClientID%>").value;
            var dob2 = document.getElementById("<%=DoB2.ClientID%>");
            if ((firstname2 != "" || surname2 != "" || relation2 != "") && dob2.value == "") {
                errorMessage += "Second DoB needs to be filled. \n";
                error=true;
            }
            var firstname3 = document.getElementById("<%=child3FN.ClientID%>").value;
            var surname3 = document.getElementById("<%=child3LN.ClientID%>").value;
            var relation3 = document.getElementById("<%=ddlRelationship3.ClientID%>").value;
            var dob3 = document.getElementById("<%=Dob3.ClientID%>");
            if ((firstname3 != "" || surname3 != "" || relation3 != "") && dob3.value == "") {
                errorMessage += "Third DoB needs to be filled. \n";
                error=true;
            }

            var firstname4 = document.getElementById("<%=child4FN.ClientID%>").value;
            var surname4 = document.getElementById("<%=child4LN.ClientID%>").value;
            var relation4 = document.getElementById("<%=ddlRelationship4.ClientID%>").value;
            var dob4 = document.getElementById("<%=DoB4.ClientID%>");
            if ((firstname4 != "" || surname4 != "" || relation4 != "") && dob4.value == "") {
                errorMessage += "Fourth DoB needs to be filled. \n";
                error=true;
            }

            if (error) {
                alert(errorMessage);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

The problem is, that I cannot use a for loop as asp doesn't accept a javascript value for the following source

```
<tr>
                 <th>
                        Child one:
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="child1FN" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="child1LN" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRelationship1" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="DoB1" runat="server" Culture="English (Australia)" MinDate="1 Jan 1920" class="datePickerDOB">
                        </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Child two:
                    </th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="child2FN" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="child2LN" runat="server" />
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRelationship2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="DoB2" runat="server" Culture="English (Australia)" MinDate="1 Jan 1920" class="datePickerDOB">
                        </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                    </td>
                </tr> . . .
```

I've only shown the first two rows of the source which has been simplified and removed styling tags for legibility. Like I wrote; there's 4 rows and they're similar to the above code but with just a different ID.

I was wondering if anybody had any suggestions to improve this code?

**Rendered Telerick Code**

```
<span class="riSingle RadInput RadInput_MetroTouch" id="ctl00_cphBody_DoB1_dateInput_wrapper" style="width: 100%; display: block;">
    <input name="ctl00$cphBody$DoB1$dateInput" class="riTextBox riEnabled" id="ctl00_cphBody_DoB1_dateInput" style="padding-left: 2px; font-size: 12px;" type="text">
    <input name="ctl00_cphBody_DoB1_dateInput_ClientState" id="ctl00_cphBody_DoB1_dateInput_ClientState" type="hidden" value='{"enabled":true,"emptyMessage":"","validationText":"","valueAsString":"","minDateStr":"20202020-JanJan-0101-0000-0101-0000","maxDateStr":"99999999-DecDec-3131-0000-1212-0000","lastSetTextBoxValue":""}' autocomplete="off">
</span>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what HTML the telrik DatePicker Control renders? As each of your "groups" is in a table row you will be able to use that to validate on a per row basis.

Comment: I've added it toward the end of my question, I don't see how it will help though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giv the container an ID, this will make your life easier with jQuery (and is a little more efficient than using classes etc as selectors). Also, add a class to your "data" rows

```
<table id="formElements">
     <tr><th>Child 1</th></tr>
     <tr class="data"><!-- Form Elelemt Cells --></tr>
     <!-- etc -->
</table>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var formTable = $("#formElements");
    /*console.log(formTable);  */


    $("#submitBtn").click(function (index) {
    var errorMessage = "";
    var error = false;

    //Use the fact we have the elements in a row to our advantage
    $(formTable).find("tr.data").each(function (index) {
        var firstName = $(this).find("td:nth-child(1) input").val();
        var lastName = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2) input").val();
        var relationship = $(this).find("td:nth-child(3) select").val();
        //Taking a punt the value is in the hidden form field for DOB;
        var dob = $(this).find("td:nth-child(4) input[type='hidden']").val();

        //Use console to try and work out what telrik uses to hold the data
        console.log($(this).find("td:nth-child(4) input[type='hidden']"));
        console.log($(this).find("td:nth-child(4) input[type='text']"));

        if ((firstName != "" || lastName != "" || relationship != "") && dob == "") {
            errorMessage += "DoB " + (index + 1) + " needs to be filled. \n";
            error = true;
        }
   });

   if (error) {
       alert(errorMessage);
       return false;
   }
  });
});
```

This is a little quick and dirty and handling the telrick control could be tricky.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/68BYf/1/)

If you can use ASP.net inbuild validators to validate the telrik control you may be better off using them. Even stil, using a custom ASP.net validator should work in a similar fasion.

**Update**

I've added a couple of debug lines using `console.log` to try and help with the telrik controls.

**Slighly hacky version**

Keep the HTML as per above.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var formTable = $("#formElements");
    /*console.log(formTable);  */

    //Create an array of the DatePicker controls
    //You could replace the jQuery selectro with:
    //document.getElementById("<%=DoB1.ClientID%>")
    var arrDoB = new Array( 
                     $("#<%=DoB1.ClientID%>"),
                     $("#<%=DoB2.ClientID%>"),
                     $("#<%=DoB3.ClientID%>"),
                     $("#<%=DoB4.ClientID%>")
                 );

    $("#submitBtn").click(function (index) {
    var errorMessage = "";
    var error = false;

    //Use the fact we have the elements in a row to our advantage
    $(formTable).find("tr.data").each(function (index) {
        var firstName = $(this).find("td:nth-child(1) input").val();
        var lastName = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2) input").val();
        var relationship = $(this).find("td:nth-child(3) select").val();

        //Get the value of the datepicker control from the array
        var dob = arrDoB[index].value;

        if ((firstName != "" || lastName != "" || relationship != "") && dob == "") {
            errorMessage += "DoB " + (index + 1) + " needs to be filled. \n";
            error = true;
        }
   });

   if (error) {
       alert(errorMessage);
       return false;
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to grab the dob value and just alert it, but no luck. I've tried both with input[type='text'] and input[type='hidden']. I've also tried as both alert(dob); and alert(dob.value); Nothing but blank alerts pop up... and yeah, Ideally I don't want to use alert as the validation message, I'd rather use the inbuilt ASP validation, just no clue how I'd implement it yet..

Comment: Look into the wonders of using `console.log` for debugging. Much more usefule than alerts! http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2011/05/26/console-log-say-goodbye-to-javascript-alerts-for-debugging.aspx

Comment: Very handy, thank you. At least its easier now to see a bunch of 'undefined's haha. Most likely I'm logging it incorrectly as I've never used it.

Comment: Here's an updated filde to show what you should be getting with console.log: http://jsfiddle.net/68BYf/2/ . Were you getting DOB's succesfully with your existing code? If so I think I have a bit of a dodgy hack.

Comment: My existing code worked fine as I was calling the control element by its exact id. For some reason, your jfiddle always states there needs to be a dob input even if the DOB has been filled initially BEFORE validation..

Comment: My fiddle is just  a rough demo...I was working on the assumption that the telrik conrol stores the actual date in a hidden field, its a hidden field that I'm validating against, but I'm not updating that hidden field anywhere, so it will always fail validation.

Comment: Ah ok, fair enough. I'm looking at the console of the hidden and text type DoB Controls, theres 8 in total. Anyway, what should I be looking for? It's too large to paste here.

Comment: Edit: there appears to be 4 Hidden input fields within the Telerick Date Selector. Dear god. Within the second hidden field the value is saved, its rendered HTML is: "<input name="ctl00_cphBody_DoB1_calendar_SD" id="ctl00_cphBody_DoB1_calendar_SD" type="hidden" value="[[2014,7,31]]">"

Comment: Just to clarify then, as you have 4 date pickers, you then have 16 hidden fields in total, 4 per row?

Comment: If the value is reliably in the 2nd hidden field, replace `var dob = $(this).find("td:nth-child(4) input[type='hidden']").val();` with `var dob = $(this).find("td:nth-child(4) input[type='hidden']:nth-child(2)").val();`

Comment: Affirmative. There is also a value stored within the type="text" field and there are two fields within that 'control' as well. it rendered HTML: "<input name="ctl00$cphBody$DoB1" title="Visually hidden input created for functionality purposes." class="rdfd_ radPreventDecorate" id="ctl00_cphBody_DoB1" style="margin: ..."

Comment: Ok. I've got it, $(this).find("td:nth-child(4) input[type='text']").val() returns the raw value as 2014-07-10 if the input was july 10th.  The other hidden fields were giving me arrays of values and JSON like strings. Ill let you know how it goes :)

Comment: Sweet... don't forget to up vote using the up arrow on the left and/or check the tick to accept the answer. Your next mission, should you decide to accept it, is to adapt what you've learnt with this and use is to implement asp:CusotmValidator. You'll be able to use a lot of the jQuery we've got here for client side. Hint learn how to find the `tr` ancesor of the active validation control. The tricky part will be serverside validation. Think along the lines of 4 functoions, which will call one main function containing the main logic.